Rx operator which waits for subscription to finish
I want to combine two observables, say SendMoves and Results to produce SendMovesAndGetResults.
Subscription to SendMoves ultimately causes values to be pushed down Results. Therefore subscription to Results needs to complete before any subscription to SendMoves to avoid a race condition.
As a demonstration of code with a race condition consider:
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

Test m = new Test();
m.RaceConditionTest();
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


internal class Test
{
   public void RaceConditionTest()
   {
      // by subscribing to the results before the moves are sent you
      // might think you are guaranteed to get all of the results
      // but subscribe is asynchronous with no obvious way of knowing when it has completed.
      WhenResults([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(r => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Result {r}"));
      SendMoves([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe();
   }

   private readonly Subject<int> mMoveResults = new Subject<int>();
   private IObservable<int> WhenResults(IEnumerable<int> moveTokens) =>
       moveTokens
       .ToObservable()
       .SelectMany(i => mMoveResults.Where(r => r == i).FirstAsync().Trace($"mMoveResult {i}"));

   private IObservable<int> SendMoves(List<int> moves) =>
       Observable.Create<int>(o =>
       {
          foreach (var move in moves)
          {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Sending move {move}");
             mMoveResults.OnNext(move);
          }

          o.OnCompleted();
          return Disposable.Empty;
       });
}

public static class ObservableExtensions
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Allows us to trace the observable pipeline. 
   /// Specifically, we can trace the subscribe, onNext, onError and onCompleted events for all observers.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TSource"></typeparam>
   /// <param name="source"></param>
   /// <param name="name"></param>
   /// <param name="itemToString"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public static IObservable<TSource> Trace<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, string name)
   {
      var id = 0;

      return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
      {
         var id1 = ++id;
         Action<string, object> trace = (m, v) => Debug.WriteLine($"{name}-{id1}: {m}({v})");
         trace("Subscribe", "");
         var disposable = source.Subscribe(
             v =>
             {
                trace("OnNext", v.ToString());
                observer.OnNext(v);
             },
             e =>
             {
                trace("OnError", e.Message);
                observer.OnError(e);
             },
             () =>
             {
                trace("OnCompleted", "");
                observer.OnCompleted();
             });


         return () =>
         {
            trace("Dispose", "");
            disposable.Dispose();
         };
      });
   }
}

The output is:
Sending move 1
'ConsoleApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.8\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Sending move 2
Sending move 3
Sending move 4
Sending move 5
Sending move 6
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (16108) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
mMoveResult 1-1: Subscribe()
mMoveResult 2-1: Subscribe()
mMoveResult 3-1: Subscribe()
mMoveResult 4-1: Subscribe()
mMoveResult 5-1: Subscribe()
mMoveResult 6-1: Subscribe()

Which shows the moves got sent before we subscribed to the results in a meaningful way. Interestingly the same output is seen from a WPF app without the need of SubscribeOn. Is there a standard way of dealing with this? How can you know that a subscription is fully setup before calling code that will start pushing values.

If ever you do a return Disposable.Empty; then you are probably doing something wrong.

When I run the code I get the result immediately after each send.

You should avoid Observable.Create when a simple moves.ToObservable() will suffice.

You say "subscribe is asynchronous", but it is not. It's synchronous.

The code you've posted doesn't match the output. There's no - in the Trace call. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Hi Enigmativity. Thanks for looking at this. I was running the original Test class code from a WPF app. This seems to account for the difference in output we have seen. I've now updated my example to a full Console App. The only way I could provoke a similar behaviour was to use the SubscribeOn operator. In terms of the output I was using my own Trace implementation (now included). Is there a standard Trace implementation people use?

If subscribe is synchronous how could the merge operator successfully merge cold observables like this?
var odd = new int[] { 1, 3 }.ToObservable();
var even = new int[] { 2, 4 }.ToObservable();
odd.Merge(even).Subscribe(v => Debug.WriteLine(v));

output:
1
2
3
4

@Mark What is your goal in using SelectMany() to access the mMoveResults subject to try to read the matching element and return only one element you are looking for, to combine them back via SelectMany()? It is unclear what you are trying to do there. Why do you not subscribe on the mMoveResults subject directly and react on the values generated from SendMoves()? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do (is this an XY problem?)

@Progman Hi, thanks for taking a look. The example has been simplified compared to my actual code. I'm fudging things a little. In reality I'm making a robot move and collecting move data as it does. Via TCP/IP the robot reports move data, move start, and move end messages. When a move is requested a token is used to allow each individual move to be identified. I convert all these messages into observables. In the actual code the SelectMany is combining move data that is specific to each move (using SkipUntil and TakeUntil on the move start and move end observable).
